# Ajax and admin requests stopped functioning by entering mod-rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to url-rewriting.

I have written few rewrite rules in the .htaccess file. My problem is that the ajax request and the admin section **(both of which are being managed by different files, named ajax.php and admin.php) not working at all.**

Here is what I am trying to achieve using mod-rewrite :

The URL :  `http://websitename/index.php?page=rr&cn=abc&cid=1` 
should look like this : `http://websitename/rr/abc/1` 
in the addressbar of browser

and

The URL (having only 'page' value): `http://websitename/index.php?page=register` 
should look like this : `http://websitename/register` 
in the addressbar of browser

and

The URL : `http://websitename/index.php?page=i&in=banking&iid=12` 
should look like this : `http://websitename/industry/banking/12` 
in the addressbar of browser

and

The URL : `http://websitename/index.php?page=cr&cn=pqr&rid=12` 
should look like this : `http://websitename/cr/pqr/12` 
in the addressbar of browser

So far I am able to do this using the following rules but the request made to **ajax.php and admin.php along with some parameters** are not working at all (page not found error).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&companyname=$2&companyid=$3%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&industryname=$2&industryid=$3%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/review/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&companyname=$2&reviewid=$3 [L]
```

All the three mod-rewrite rules work fine but the ajax requests that is done through a separate file named "ajax.php" are not working (page not found error comes)

i.e. the following URLs should work with above mod-rewrite rules 
`http://websitename/ajax.php?action=vote` 
 and
`http://websitename/admin.php?page=home`

(don't want to have mod-rewrite rules for the files ajax.php and admin.php)

But I am not able to successfully do it for ajax.php and admin.php

Please help me on this. I am really stuck on this.

Thanks

Comment: can you give examples of urls and what is happening when you don't comment out the first one.

Comment: We need to see urls to help.  What is the url for CSS -- which url isn't rewriting correctly.  Edit and update the question with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, it appears to me your second rewrite rule would be catching both of the URL's you don't want to have rewritten.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Both these URL's would be picked up in the above rewrite rule

- http://websitename/ajax.php?action=vote
- http://websitename/admin.php?page=home

I suggest changing your htaccess to the following, all it's trying to do is catch the admin.php, or ajax.php calls and send them straight through unchanged (I haven't checked this but it should be ok):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/ajax.php(.*)$ /ajax.php$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/admin.php(.*)$ /admin.php$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&companyname=$2&companyid=$3%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&industryname=$2&industryid=$3%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/review/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&companyname=$2&reviewid=$3 [L]
```

Comment: This does not work. The ajax request made to the ajax.php is not working. "Page not found" error.

Comment: Perhaps try removing the absolute reference and make it relative (instead of '/ajax.php..', change to just 'ajax.php...') it may fix it and match the way your other rules appear. Have you checked to ensure the ajax.php file exists in the location being referenced as well if the relative change doesn't work?

Comment: here is a workaround/hack that I found while fiddling with the rules. If I specify the rules in some order than it works perfectly. i.e. I added the ajax.php and admin.php rule after the last line in the answer above., and then I moved the index.php?page=$1%{QUERY_STRING} rule below the ajax.php and admin.php rewrite rule. still testing it for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

An offhand guess, maybe the ajax.php and admin.php get assimilated into rules 2 or 4 because of the leading '/'. I'm a bit hazy on the exact workings of mod_rewrite, but it might have something to do with it.

Try add rule by rule and test the admin.php and ajax.php pages to figure out which rules are making those pages fail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Last rule created problems that is why I posted my question over here. How can I make all the rules work simultaneously without breaking the ajax and admin requests? I know the task is not impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Prefix every `RewriteRule` with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
```

With it your rules will work only when they reference an inexistent file. Requests for exiting files particularly `ajax.php` and `admin.php` will be left verbatim.